# What's the process of ClickHouse primary index

Tags: clickhouse

As mentioned in the title, i am very confused about the ClickHouse primary index.
ClickHouse primary index used these files: primary.idx, [primaryField].mrk, [primaryField].bin.
Where is MarkRange stored and how it works?
How do these relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primary.idx -- contains primary columns keys values

```
20.13.1.5273
create table X(A Int64, S String) 
Engine=MergeTree order by A settings index_granularity=4096, min_bytes_for_wide_part=0;
insert into X select number, toString(number) from numbers(32768);

cd /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/X/all_1_1_0/

order by A -- A Int64  -- primary.idx has A value with size 8 bytes one after another, 
default granularity is 4096
primary.idx === 0, 4096, 8192 

check 

od -l -j 0 -N 8 primary.idx    #skip zero bytes read 8
0000000                    0

od -l -j 8 -N 8 primary.idx    #skip 8 bytes read 8
0000010                 4096

od -l -j 16 -N 8 primary.idx   #skip 16 bytes read 8
0000020                 8192      0


mrk files contains offsets to bin (column) from primary key

od -l -j 0 -N 24 S.mrk2
0000000                    0                    0
0000020                 4096

0  offset in compressed file (S.bin)
0  offset in decompressed block
4096 number of rows in granula

od -l -j 48 -N 24 S.mrk2
0000060                    0                39850
0000100                 4096

0  offset in compressed file (S.bin)
39850  offset in decompressed block
4096 number of rows in granula

od -l -j 72 -N 24 S.mrk2
0000110                    0                62618
0000130                 4096

0  offset in compressed file (S.bin)
62618  offset in decompressed block
4096 number of rows in granula


4096+4096+4096 = 12288 -- third granula of S column must contain strings with 12288+

check
dd status=none bs=1 skip=0 if=S.bin|clickhouse-compressor -d|dd status=none bs=1 skip=62618 count=50|hexdump -C
00000000  05 31 32 32 38 38 05 31  32 32 38 39 05 31 32 32  |.12288.12289.122|
00000010  39 30 05 31 32 32 39 31  05 31 32 32 39 32 05 31  |90.12291.12292.1|
00000020  32 32 39 33 05 31 32 32  39 34 05 31 32 32 39 35  |2293.12294.12295|
00000030  05 31                                             |.1|
00000032
```

some pictures in russian https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clickhouse/clickhouse-presentations/master/meetup27/adaptive_index_granularity.pdf

Comment: thanks, Can i understand this way:  1. get the query condaction, then compare with the primary.idx, get the index(like 0000010), 2.then use this index to mrk file get the offset of this block. the index in mrk is primary_index*3(each primary_index has three info in mrk file). 3. go to bin file find the real data, from the second process can get the offset in bin and offset in decompressed block.

Comment: one question is what's the format in bin file. does it like  { [header][compressed_block][header][compressed_block]  }

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/src/Compression/CompressionInfo.h#L15

Comment: od -l -j 0 -N 8 primary.idx    #skip zero bytes read 8
0000000                    0

why need skip 8 bytes, how does clickhouse define it, if the data is large, it will be change?

Comment: @J.A.R.V.I.S primarykey=order by A = A Int64 = 8 bytes. In case of more complicated PK it will be more  complicated, null-terminated strings, run-length encoded arrays, ..