# ClickHouse: Does the non-primary column store the value of related primary column in its data file

Tags: indexing, clickhouse

In ClickHouse, I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    a UInt8,
    b UInt8
)
ENGINE =MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY(a)
```

There is only one partition[`all`] and two column data files[`a.bin`,`b.bin`].

**Does the data file of the non-primary column `b` store the value of its related primary column `a`**?

- If no. How to get the value of b if execute the sql `select b from Mytable where a = 1`?
- If yes. How the query process runs? The query engine has to process the whole `b.bin` to get the row with `a=1`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198241/whats-the-process-of-clickhouse-primary-index

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/improving-query-performance/sparse-primary-indexes

Answer (score 0):

No, column `b` will store in the seperate `b.bin`, but each block sorted by `a` value

During processing `select b from Mytable where a = 1`
First of all, cause you don't have `partition by` so will not read minmax index in partition.dat in each dir /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/MyTable/

but will seek+read (o log(n) ) primary.idx from memory which contains `a` values for each 8192 row, and found granula number

after it will seek to granula number and read b.mrk2 file, which contains two offsets for granual, first offset1 inside compressed file, second offset2 inside uncompressed data and rows count in granula

after it will seek+read b.bin file (use kernel page cache), will uncompress it and show b values in your result set from offset2

Comment: Thanks for replay. So the process is:
1. use primary.idx to get the mark number(such as `n`)
2. read b.mrk by the mark number `n` to get the compressed and uncompress offset in b.bin, then get the value of b.
 Am i right? Btw, is it the b.mrk file or b.mrk2(i think the index granularity is default 8192)

Comment: Does the `b.bin` store the related row number? How the engine find the value of `a` if run the sql `select a from MyTable where b=1`?

Comment: No, b.bin doesn't store row number as i know, you can't read properly .bin file without .mrk

Comment: b.mrk will read from offset for "granula N"

Comment: I just want to how different columns in same row are connected. If run sql `select b from MyTable where a = 1`.  Assume the `a=1` is in the second row of the first granula (N=0)，so the engine will use `a.mrk` and `b.mrk` to get the first granula data from `a.bin` and `b.bin`, and then align them(first enrty of `a` is aligned with first entry of `b`, the second is the same..). So the engine will read the second entry of b to get the result. Am i right?